# How to rename an entity in Entity Framework database first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I am using EF 6.0 and DB first approach.

I have loaded my model from DB and everything is working fine. Now I want to rename few entity name.

When I rename an entity it gives me below error.

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
>
> The relationship 'FK_PL_Attribution_AttributionGroup_ID' was not loaded because the type 'AttributionGroupLevel' is not available.

The entity name was `AttributionGroup1` and I renamed it to `AttributionGroupLevel`.

What is the right way to rename an entity and why it is failing to validate the schema?

Comment: where did you try renaming? in generated `.cs` file?

Comment: I opened Model browse and navigate to entity and renamed it.
I also tried with .cs file but  no luck.

Comment: Delete your entity 'AttributionGroup1' and click 'Update Model from Database'.

Comment: Are you renaming it on the database as well? If you're going to rename it on the ef. It is wise to rename the table/procedure on the backend for consistency. Since ef just loads your database objects, it is wise for future use.

Comment: I cannot rename it into DB as it is old DB and in use for different applications. In my application, there is already an entity with same name called AttributionGroup, so EF is generating like AttributionGroup1. I am not good with name.

Comment: Tried with deleting the entity AttributionGroup1 and update the model. This just re-add the entity AttributionGroup1. Nothing special.

Comment: I thought you were renaming the table in the database.